# what kind of encoding is this and how to decode it

Tags: lua, deobfuscation, grand-theft-auto

I asked my friend and he said that it's AST. But I'm not sure and don't know how to decode it.

`SCE = {} SCE[0x3B06D907] = function() return SCE[0x16D35994]({SCE[0x2CCB9B3C](), SCE[0x24AA4743](), SCE[0x1E716305](), SCE[0x2A7C5767](), SCE[0x165A6AC3](), SCE[0x1D0ACBC5](), SCE[0x3B79C46E](), SCE[0x1D4DE704](), SCE[0x27680DA1](), SCE[0x1C317CFE](), SCE[0x316934F5](), SCE[0x18C41DEC](), SCE[0x2A7D468A](), SCE[0x3A8183EA](), SCE[0x28E77657](), SCE[0x3159E5B8](), SCE[0x1ACECA1C]() , SCE[0x285218A3](), SCE[0x341688EA](), SCE[0x26DCC896](), SCE[0x1A80B2E1](), SCE[0x17D18EE4](), SCE[0x29C39207](), SCE[0x27BA5263](), SCE[0x166769AE](), SCE[0x1A81C222](), SCE[0x3549905A]()}) end SCE[0x3813D8D1] = '0 3 2 0 3 9 0 3 3 0 4 0 0 3 6 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 3 0 4 0 0 3 8 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 4 0 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 7 0 3 7 0 3 3 0 3 4 0 3 5 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 5 0 3 2 0 ' SCE[0x38B2F6A7] = '3 2 0 3 8 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 3 0 4 0 0 4 0 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 9 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 6 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 3 0 3 7 0 3 3 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 6 0 3 2 0 3 ' SCE[0x2D2D5130] = function(Ox26464833) if SCE[0x38B2F6A7] == SCE[0x23AC3D05] or SCE[0x38B2F6A7] == SCE[0x3B509C73] or SCE[0x142600A7](SCE[0x38B2F6A7]) <= SCE[0x2F7A2C68] then return else Ox26464833 = SCE[0x2EC981D9] end return SCE[0x38B2F6A7] end SCE[0x3111B14D] = '2 0 3 9 0 3 3 0 4 0 0 3 8 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 9 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 7 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 4 0 3 5 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 6 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 5 0 3 3 0 3 4 0 3 5 0 3 2 0 3 2 ' SCE[0x32D39C31] = function(Ox26464833) if SCE[0x3111B14D] == SCE[0x23AC3D05] or SCE[0x3111B14D] == SCE[0x3B509C73] or SCE[0x142600A7](SCE[0x3111B14D]) <= SCE[0x2F7A2C68] then return else Ox26464833 = SCE[0x14EF2C5C] end return SCE[0x3111B14D] end SCE[0x290A5F73] = '0 3 6 0 3 3 0 4 0 0 4 0 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 7 0 3 2 0 3 3 0 3 6 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 5 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 3 9 0 3 3 0 4 0 0 3 6 0 3 3 0 4 0 0 3 8 0 3 3 0 4 0 0 4 0 0 3 2 0 3 2 0 ' SCE[0x1AD49A98] = function(Ox26464833) if SCE[0x290A5F73] == SCE[0x23AC3D05] or SCE[0x290A5F73] == SCE[0x3B509C73] or SCE[0x142600A7](SCE[0x290A5F73]) <= SCE[0x2F7A2C68] then return`

Comment: Please upload the whole script (for example, to pastebin.com)

Comment: `what kind of encoding is this` - This is an interesting kind of obfuscation.  Especially I like remarkable variable name `Ox26464833` :-) It's not a zero at the beginning.

Comment: https://anotepad.com/notes/c33xrk2 Here the notepad of the whole script

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff Excuse me do you have discord or facebook? i have some obfuscate that want to discuss with you

Comment: Neither.  But my email at gmail.com is easy to google.